# Как отправлять структуру через сокеты?

Tags: c, сеть, tcp

Cервер:

```
typedef struct send_data
{
    char a[50];
    char b[50];
    char c[50];
}send_data;

send_data sd;
while(recv(sock,&sd,sizeof(sd),0))
{
    printf("sd:%s\n",sd.a );
}
```

Клиент:

```
send_data sd;
strcpy(sd.a,"Hello");
strcpy(sd.b,"");

send(sock,(void*)&sd,sizeof(sd),0);
```

Почему-то когда я один раз отправляю структуру sd серверу, на сервере три раза срабатывает recv, в итоге выводится это:

```
sd:Hello
sd:
sd:�:Q6�U
```

Почему так происходит и как это исправить?

Вот так запускаю  слушающий сокет на сервере:

```
struct sockaddr_in client;
struct sockaddr_in addr;
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_port = htons(port);
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);
main_sock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
bind(socket,(struct sockaddr*)&addr,sizeof(addr));
listen(main_sock,10);
client_sock=accept(main_sock,(struct sockaddr*)&client,(int*)&size_client)
```

Comment: Вы должны создать поверх tcp свой протокол и автомат для сбора пакетов. И не забывать обрабатывать ошибки.

Comment: @Croessmah, обработки ошибок нет для уменьшения кода на стековерфлоу

Comment: никто вам не гарантирует, что если вы сделали один `send`, то получите данные за один `recv`.

Comment: @Iamnotgey а ядро какое?

Comment: @eri, ядро чего?

Comment: @Iamnotgey по стандарту `recv()` возврашает или количество считаных байт или -1 если прошла ошибка , а `while` что 1 что -1 будет проходит цикл . Лучше внутри цикла проверить что вернул `recv()` тогда будет понятно ошибка или не все данные считаны .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

C сокет выдает данные по мере поступления. Интересно конечно почему происходит flush по \0. Это скорее воспринимается как конец сообщения. Добавьте в вопрос как запускаете сокет - попробуем повторить.

MSG_WAITALL для recv флаг поможет читать структуру целиком, но не гарантирует этого - нужны дополнительные проверки.

Мусор в конце потому, что переменная не инициированна.

Comment: Добавил, MSG_WAITALL работает

Comment: Для того он и придуман

Comment: Почему так происходит конечно не понял, наверное мне для начала нужно изучить протокол tcp, благодарю за помощь

Comment: Recv читает до конца сообщения, \0 в конце строки он принимает за конец сообщения.

Comment: Теперь все понял

Comment: @eri нулевой байт никак не воспринимается `recv`-ом. Это просто очередной байт.

Comment: @Croessmah а ядром? А стеком tcp?   Некоторые байты не такие обычные - они называются управляющими не просто так. Напишите новый ответ, в котором объясните почему recv из 150 запрошенных прочел только 5 байт

Comment: @eri никаких "управляющих" байт в tcp-протоколе не предусмотрено. Данные могут быть любые. У ТС'а цикл приема пакета неправильный - он не учитывает то, что на один `send` может понадобиться несколько `recv` и наоборот. Как видите, добавление `MSG_WAITALL` помогло. Помогло потому, что `recv` с этм флагом блокирует поток до тех пор, пока не примет все запрошенные данные. Без этого флага `recv` не обязан их ждать все. У ТС'а на первой итерации было принято сколько-то байт, вторая итерация перезаписала ранее принятые данные, а следом третья итерация сделала тоже самое.

Comment: 150байт это один пакет, тсп бьет его на 3 посылки почему? Сколько recv нужно это другой вопрос. Вопрос почему одно сообщение разбито на три!

Comment: @eri с чего вы взяли? Пакеты могут быть считаны/отправлены как угодно, даже если не учитывать окна и т.д.

Comment: @eri https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.2.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r2.bpxbd00/rcv.htm: ".... Stream sockets act like streams of information with no boundaries separating data. For example, if applications A and B are connected with a stream socket and application A sends 1000 bytes, *each call to this function can return 1 byte, or 10 bytes, or the entire 1000 bytes*. Therefore, applications using stream sockets should place this call in a loop, calling this function until all data has been received."

Comment: Да и понятно что они должны читать через цикл. Но вопрос в другом: почему блок разбит так мелко? у меня не получается пока повторить этот фокус - похоже надо писать на си или автор шлет больше 150 байт в реальном коде

Comment: @eri у человека вон 100 байт бьет )))
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295737/case-when-blocking-recv-returns-less-than-requested-bytes

Comment: что за магия с 50 байт?) как её повторить?

Comment: @eri, скорей всего ТС что-то не договаривает. Я бы поставил на то, что на самом деле он отправляет куда больше данных, а код в вопросе умозрительный… Действительно, на практике при слабой нагрузке и в элементарном варианте фрагменты меньше 536 байт не должны разбиваться и почти всегда должны приходить одним куском. На это, конечно, нельзя полагаться с программной точки зрения… но **Croessmah** прав — нули не имеют ни какого отношения к тому, как сегментируется поток при чтении/записи из/в сокеты. И из того, что привёл ТС совсем не очевидно, что вывод разбивается именно на 50-байтовые куски.

Comment: не должны иметь значения, но может тут контроллер на проводе или реализация libc где нули имеют значение или чтото связанное с 50 байт

Comment: @eri не может быть такой реализации даже теоретически. Только если жестокие баги, но такая реализация не будет использоваться.